# TexLive - tlmgr: package aeb-pro not found neither locally nor remote!

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

Scratching my head on this one.. have installed TexLive from current on ubuntu 20.

Running tlmgr update -list tells me its happy and there is nothing to update. I've added the tlcontrib repo and looking at the URL I can see the list of packages.

I want to install aeb-pro

But what I am seeing is things like this

```
sudo tlmgr install aeb-pro
tlmgr: package repositories
    main = https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
    https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib/ = https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib/ (verified)
tlmgr install: package aeb-pro not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Running `sudo tlmgr list | grep aeb` I get a load of

```
tlmgr: package acmtrans not found neither locally nor remote!
.
.
.
tlmgr: package aeb-pro not found neither locally nor remote!
```

I'm assuming I've missed the instruction on how to load in the repo in the first place? or the ctan mirror points wrong?

**Update:**
I removed Ubuntu's TexLive and installed the 2021 release from TexLive itself. I also added the contrib repo.

When I list packages - I can see aeb-pro being listed as being in contrib, but its complaining its not there - which is a bit confusing actually! :)

Also cross-posted this as an issue on the Tex-Live contrib github if I get an answer I will post back here

Comment: Exactly what have you installed? AFAIK `tlmgr` from Ubuntu cannot be used to install packages as those who packaged TeXLive for Ubuntu rather want users to use `apt` to install stuff.

Comment: Additionally https://ctan.org/pkg/aeb-pro?lang=en lists that `aeb-pro` is **not** available for TeXLive.

Comment: aeb-pro is only in miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but it does appear to be in tlcontrib https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib/archive/aeb-pro.r336.tar.xz

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah right, I could install from there.

Answer (score 1):

OK turns out to be an error in the setup of the tlcontrib repo.. from github

```
I guess I see your problem, thanks a lot for reporting it.
You followed the advice on https://contrib.texlive.info/ which said

  tlmgr repository add https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib
  tlmgr pinning add tlcontrib "*"

Which in fact is incorrect, since you didn't assign the tag tlcontrib to the url https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib

I have now updated the page to the correct

  tlmgr repository add https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib tlcontrib
  tlmgr pinning add tlcontrib "*"

(note the final tlcontrib at the end of the first line, which was missing before)

So how can you fix that? The best way is to do

    remove the old entry: tlmgr repository remove https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib/
    add it again with the correct tag: tlmgr repository add https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlcontrib tlcontrib

After that you should be able to run tlmgr install aeb-pro

Note: depending on your setup it is necessary that you prefix tlmgr with sudo so that the above commands read like sudo tlmgr ....
```